# 64 bit HVM guest freezes while booting on Debian Lenny 64 bit Xen hypervisor

Tags: xen, debian-lenny, hypervisor, 64-bit, x86-64

I'm trying to create an x86 64 bit guest machine on an old Debian Lenny x86 64 bit hypervisor using HVM. The physical CPU is a first generation Intel i7 with VT-x support. Xen recognizes the VT-x support with the line (XEN) HVM: VMX enabled when running xm dmesg.

The Xen version according to xm info is 3.2.

I tried with newest installer ISO images of Debian Squeeze (6.0) and Ubuntu Oneiric Ocelot (11.10). The x86 64 bit version freezes the guest system shortly after starting, if I mount the x86 32 bit installer image, everything runs fine.

How can I fix this?

IRC user krt in ##xen on irc.freenode.net recommended setting acpi = 0 in the guest configuration file. This did **not** solve this problem.

Here is the guest configuration file I'm currently using:

```
arch = 'amd64'

device_model = '/usr/lib/xen-default/bin/qemu-dm'

#
#  Kernel + memory size
#
kernel      = '/usr/lib/xen-default/boot/hvmloader'

builder = 'hvm'
acpi = 0
#xen_platform_pci = 0

memory      = 1024
shadow_memory = 8

#
#  Disk device(s).
#
#root        = '/dev/sda2 ro'
disk        = [
                  'file:/var/lib/libvirt/images/ubuntu-11.10-desktop-amd64.iso,xvdc:cdrom,r',
                  'phy:/dev/system/fraumann-root,xvda,w',
              ]

# boot on floppy (a), hard disk (c) or CD-ROM (d)
# default: hard disk, cd-rom, floppy
boot = 'dc'

#
#  Hostname
#
name        = 'fraumann'

#
#  Networking
#
vif         = [ 'ip=1.2.3.4,mac=00:16:3E:9F:3C:31' ] # IP changed for the public

sdl = 0
vnc = 1
vnclisten = 'localhost'
vncconsole = 1
stdvga = 0
serial = 'pty'
usbdevice = 'tablet'

#
#  Behaviour
#
on_poweroff = 'destroy'
on_reboot   = 'restart'
on_crash    = 'restart'

vcpus = 4
extra = 'xencons=tty1'
```

Comment: check the 
 /var/log/xen/qemu/*log for the working and non-working one

Comment: @ToddDeshane I only have /var/log/xen/qemu-dm-NN.log files where NN is the domain id. The log for the 32 bit working machine and the 64 bit malfunctioning one are completely identical apart of the ids being different. No luck there, I guess.

Comment: OK. So the next place to look would be the xend logs (/var/log/xend). If those are no good we can turn up the verbosity of errors in the xend config file.

Comment: Also, I think this question and discussion might be better on the xen users mailing list: http://lists.xen.org/mailman/listinfo/xen-users

Comment: I just replaced the server where this problem was happening, so I don't care anymore about this.